# Database comment/description in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to save extra text information (comment, description, etc...) about databases in MySQL.

Something like:

```
SELECT TABLE_COMMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES;
```

but for database, not table?

Comment: judging from viewing PhpMyAdmin, it appears not. However just create a table and add comments as strings into the table, and call it a comment table?

Comment: I would have to know which databases have this description. I would like to know without switching between databases and checking whether they have a table with the comment. This entails that allows many queries.

Comment: To be clear: phpMyAdmin does allow you to set a database comment, but it will *not* be stored on that database itself. Instead it will be stored in phpMyAdmin's database in the 'column_info' table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cant. Mysql allows comments only for tables and columns. You would need to store it somewhere else (maybe create something like information_schema with comments).

Comment: Theoretically you can, but it serves as metadata database for mysql server so your data might get removed. Also its not very safe and clean solution as you should not put anything there yourself. But i guess it will not do any direct harm.

Answer (score 1):

From mariadb 10.5.0 there is a field SCHEMA_COMMENT in infromation_schema.schemata https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-schemata-table/ :

```
SCHEMA_COMMENT  Database comment. From MariaDB 10.5.0.
```

It is sad that this field is not widely used nor presented when listing databases. You can set comment of a database with:

```
CREATE DATABASE xxx COMMENT 'comment';
ALTER DATABASE COMMENT 'other comment';
```

Answer (score -2):

u can use system database 'mysql' - table 'databaseschema' save schema description

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mysql-database-tables/ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/system-schema.html There is no such table.