# Can I comment schema in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, comments, mysql-workbench, database-schema

Is it possible to put some comments on the databases (i.e., Schema) in MySQL Workbench? It has a menu for commenting tables but I can't find an option for commenting databases.

Thanks,

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192258/database-comment-description-in-mysql/76904177#76904177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it. The comment input box is not enabled in workbench and adding a comment is not part of the CREATE DATABASE syntax. Also, the  `information_schema`.`schemata` view doesn't have a comments column (unlike tables and columns) so I don't know how workbench would show it back to you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I comment schema in MySQL Workbench?

No. Currently the input box is greyed out and mysql-workbench does not handle databases with comments. I created a feature request.